# How to install sql server driver while creating a python api

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, odbc-sql-server-driver

I want to create a python api so that i can communicate with my database hosted on sql server. I am trying to create it with help og google cloud platform.But when i am doing it the pyodbc package is not getting installed as it has a sql drive requirement.So how should i install the sql server driver while creating it.

Comment: Hi, do you have code that you can show?

Answer (score 0):

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nYIQXfL3lpK34yl-cR1WHwMFkyEBE4qm

You should install ODBC driver for Linux before installing pyodbc as I have exemplified above.

```
!sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: Then How should i connect it to my sql server? WHat should ne the driver name in it?

Comment: Could you refer to [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows)?